# How to connect an outdoor-rated single gang jbox to an outdoor-rated "main lug" box?

Tags: electrical-panel, outdoor, junction-box

I want to attach a 120V outlet to the side of an outdoor "main lug" enclosure.

The outdoor-rated "main lug" box has knockouts on the bottom and sides.

The outdoor-rated single gang junction box has threaded holes in the back and sides.

It seems obvious to knock out one of the knockouts, and use a threaded fitting to attach the jbox flush to the side of the main lug box.

But - how to make the connection waterproof? Is there a gasket or a special fitting for this purpose? Or would using silicone caulk be good enough?

Or is there no code-compliant way to do this, and instead, I must use flexible NM conduit and watertight fittings? This is less desirable, because it is less compact.